# Running rust executable built in `rust:latest` does not execute in `debian`

Tags: docker, rust

I am using a multistaged build to build and subsequently run the built executable:

```
FROM rust:latest AS BUILDER

EXPOSE 8081

WORKDIR snitch-backend
RUN apt update -y && apt install vim libclang-dev -y
COPY . .
RUN cargo build --release

FROM debian:bookworm-slim AS RUNNER
WORKDIR snitch-backend
COPY --from=BUILDER /actix-deploy-example/target/release/actix-deploy-example ./
CMD ./actix-deploy-example
```

When I run the built image I get the following error which indicates a problem of the compiled binary (actually the container just quits. This is for reproduction taken from bashing into the container and executing the binary manually)

```
   ./actix-deploy-example: 1: ELF��^@���@8: not found
   ./actix-deploy-example: 2: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

I'm using an apple silicon M1. It works, though, if I am just running the executable in the same container as the build container (`rust:latest`).
I am a little confused because I expected the compiled binary to work in any other docker container as long as it is using the same CPU architecture beneath. But apparently I am wrong. I would appreciate someone shedding light on why this multistage build does not work as expected or what the alternative would be.

Comment: Most likely one environment is 32-bit and the other is 64-bit.

Comment: The computer is the same.

Comment: But the environment binaries and libraries may not be. You can run 32-bit binaries with a 32-bit userland on 64-bit hardware, but you can't run 32-bit binaries with a 64-bit userland on 64-bit hardware. The errors you're seeing suggest that the environment doesn't like the binary because it's the wrong architecture, so it tries executing it as a shell script, which is the standard fallback behavior for that scenario. This is why you see the specific errors that you do; those are "lines" from the binary if you interpret it as a text shell script.

Comment: In other words, the rust image may have a 32-bit userland and the debian image may have a 64-bit userland, or vice-versa.